# Android: how to refresh displayed preferences after changing its key?

Tags: android, preferences

I have a `PreferenceFragment` which is used to change the same settings for several different items. Obviously different items require preferences values to be stored with different keys. So I change the key of all preferences after creation of the fragment.

Preferences are defined as usual by xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="_key_one"
        android:title="Title of first preference" />
    [... and more Preferences]
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The PreferenceFragment where I change keys:

```
public class ItemSettingPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private String mItemKey;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mItemKey = getArguments().getString('item_key');     //this will contain name of item
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.item_settings_preferences);
        for (int i=0; i< getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++){
            final Preference pref = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i);
            pref.setKey(mItemKey + pref.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

now all Preferences have a unique key for every item, like "item1_key_one"
Unfortunately after creation those preferences load and display the values with the original key "_key_one"

How can I force the preferences to reload the values of the new keys and display those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading all related Preference classes, I found a simple solution. Since there is no public method that allowes reloading of preferences I have to use reflection.
The necessary Method I have to call is `protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue)` found within `Preference.class` or overridden by any subclass.
Since I don't know which superclass implements this method I have to iterate through all Superclasses and try to find and invoke the method until this succeeds.

```
public class ItemSettingPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private String mItemKey;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mItemKey = getArguments().getString('item_key');     //this will contain name of item
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.item_settings_preferences);
        for (int i=0; i< getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++){
            Preference pref = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i);
            pref.setKey(mItemKey + pref.getKey());

            Class iterClass = pref.getClass();
            while(iterClass != Object.class) {
                try {
                    Method m = iterClass.getDeclaredMethod("onSetInitialValue", boolean.class, Object.class);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    m.invoke(pref, true, null);
                } catch (Exception e) { }
                iterClass = iterClass.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It might not be the most performant solution, but it works fine for my case.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, a "key" is like an "id" for your preference, meaning that you cannot change a preference "key" after it is created. If you need to generate preference items dynamically then you probably should not define your preferences in XML.

Here is a sample from android example API which demonstrates how you can generate a preference from the code and not from the XML.

```
public class PreferencesFromCode extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}

private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() {
    // Root
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    // Inline preferences
    PreferenceCategory inlinePrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    inlinePrefCat.setTitle(R.string.inline_preferences);
    root.addPreference(inlinePrefCat);

    // Checkbox preference
    CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    checkboxPref.setKey("checkbox_preference");
    checkboxPref.setTitle(R.string.title_checkbox_preference);
    checkboxPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_checkbox_preference);
    inlinePrefCat.addPreference(checkboxPref);

    // Switch preference
    SwitchPreference switchPref = new SwitchPreference(this);
    switchPref.setKey("switch_preference");
    switchPref.setTitle(R.string.title_switch_preference);
    switchPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_switch_preference);
    inlinePrefCat.addPreference(switchPref);

    // Dialog based preferences
    PreferenceCategory dialogBasedPrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    dialogBasedPrefCat.setTitle(R.string.dialog_based_preferences);
    root.addPreference(dialogBasedPrefCat);

    // Edit text preference
    EditTextPreference editTextPref = new EditTextPreference(this);
    editTextPref.setDialogTitle(R.string.dialog_title_edittext_preference);
    editTextPref.setKey("edittext_preference");
    editTextPref.setTitle(R.string.title_edittext_preference);
    editTextPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_edittext_preference);
    dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(editTextPref);

    // List preference
    ListPreference listPref = new ListPreference(this);
    listPref.setEntries(R.array.entries_list_preference);
    listPref.setEntryValues(R.array.entryvalues_list_preference);
    listPref.setDialogTitle(R.string.dialog_title_list_preference);
    listPref.setKey("list_preference");
    listPref.setTitle(R.string.title_list_preference);
    listPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_list_preference);
    dialogBasedPrefCat.addPreference(listPref);

    // Launch preferences
    PreferenceCategory launchPrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    launchPrefCat.setTitle(R.string.launch_preferences);
    root.addPreference(launchPrefCat);

    /*
     * The Preferences screenPref serves as a screen break (similar to page
     * break in word processing). Like for other preference types, we assign
     * a key here so that it is able to save and restore its instance state.
     */
    // Screen preference
    PreferenceScreen screenPref = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    screenPref.setKey("screen_preference");
    screenPref.setTitle(R.string.title_screen_preference);
    screenPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_screen_preference);
    launchPrefCat.addPreference(screenPref);

    /*
     * You can add more preferences to screenPref that will be shown on the
     * next screen.
     */

    // Example of next screen toggle preference
    CheckBoxPreference nextScreenCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setKey("next_screen_toggle_preference");
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setTitle(R.string.title_next_screen_toggle_preference);
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_next_screen_toggle_preference);
    screenPref.addPreference(nextScreenCheckBoxPref);

    // Intent preference
    PreferenceScreen intentPref = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    intentPref.setIntent(new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .setData(Uri.parse("http://www.android.com")));
    intentPref.setTitle(R.string.title_intent_preference);
    intentPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_intent_preference);
    launchPrefCat.addPreference(intentPref);

    // Preference attributes
    PreferenceCategory prefAttrsCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    prefAttrsCat.setTitle(R.string.preference_attributes);
    root.addPreference(prefAttrsCat);

    // Visual parent toggle preference
    CheckBoxPreference parentCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    parentCheckBoxPref.setTitle(R.string.title_parent_preference);
    parentCheckBoxPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_parent_preference);
    prefAttrsCat.addPreference(parentCheckBoxPref);

    // Visual child toggle preference
    // See res/values/attrs.xml for the <declare-styleable> that defines
    // TogglePrefAttrs.
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.TogglePrefAttrs);
    CheckBoxPreference childCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    childCheckBoxPref.setTitle(R.string.title_child_preference);
    childCheckBoxPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_child_preference);
    childCheckBoxPref.setLayoutResource(
            a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TogglePrefAttrs_android_preferenceLayoutChild,
                    0));
    prefAttrsCat.addPreference(childCheckBoxPref);
    a.recycle();

    return root;
}
```

}

Here you will be able to **setKey()** before the preference is created.

Comment: thanks, I hoped to avoid this, as I want to have the project clearly structured, i.e have all defined preferences at the same place. Also I use some self created Preferences which are designed to only be used by XML - they don't have any Setters for their attributes - Seems I have to extend them :-/

Answer (score 0):

Most easy solution would be use separate settings names:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("MyPrefs_" + someSufix);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_my);
}
```

instead of prefixing key values.